# R code to combined two data frame with same column header but difference in data in two columns namely X1 and X2

Tags: r

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID1 = c(1:3),
                  ID2 = c(493:495),
                  ID3 = c(2635:2637),
                  X1 = c("15:03", "15:01", "03:01"),
                  X2 = c("3","3","7"),
                  X3 = c("2","2","5"),
                  X4 = c("6","6","5"),
                  X5 = c("1","24","3"))

df2 <- data.frame(ID1 = c(1:3),
                  ID2 = c(493:495),
                  ID3 = c(2635:2637),
                  X1 = c("15", "15", "03"),
                  X2 = c("03:01","03:05","07"),
                  X3 = c("2","2","5"),
                  X4 = c("6","6","5"),
                  X5 = c("1","24","3"))
```

I want combined_df looked like this:

```
data_combined <- data.frame(ID1 = c(1:3),
                            ID2 = c(493:495),
                            ID3 = c(2635:2637),
                            X1 = c("15:03", "15:01", "03:01"),
                            X2 = c("03:01","03:05","07"),
                            X3 = c("2","2","5"),
                            X4 = c("6","6","5"),
                            X5 = c("1","24","3"))
```

I tried this but not get the desired result:

```
data_combined <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(df1,df2))
```

Comment: Can somebody answer my question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to line up your `by` argument and chop out the excess:

```
merge(df1[,-5], df2[,-4], by = c('ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5'))

#   ID1 ID2  ID3 X3 X4 X5    X1    X2
# 1   1 493 2635  2  6  1 15:03 03:01
# 2   2 494 2636  2  6 24 15:01 03:05
# 3   3 495 2637  5  5  3 03:01    07
```

Or since you don't really need to match rows, just use `cbind` or `data.frame`:

```
data.frame(df1[,1:4], df2[5:8])

#   ID1 ID2  ID3    X1    X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1   1 493 2635 15:03 03:01  2  6  1
# 2   2 494 2636 15:01 03:05  2  6 24
# 3   3 495 2637 03:01    07  5  5  3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: Hi alistarie could you help me the if the df1 and df2 would be of unequal length then how I can combined them, because my data. frame is of unequal length.

Comment: Length as in rows? That's what `merge` does if there are key columns to join upon.

Comment: df1 <- data.frame(ID1 = c(1:3),ID2 = c(493:495),ID3 = c(2633:2635),X1 = c("15:03", "15:01", "03:01"),X2 = c("3","3","7"),X3 = c("2","2","5"),X4 = c("6","6","5"),X5 = c("1","24","3"))
View(df1)
df2 <- data.frame(ID1 = c(1,3,6,10,12),ID2 = c(493,495,498,502,504),ID3 = c(2633,2635,2638,2642,2644),X1 = c("15", "15", "03","07","02"),X2 = c("03:01","03:05","07","15:01","34"),X3 = c("2","2","5","34","36"),X4 = c("6","6","5","4","6"),X5 = c("1","24","3","39","40"))
View(df2)

Comment: #I want combined_df looked like this:
data_combined <- data.frame(ID1 = c(1,3,6,10,12),ID2 = c(493,495,498,502,504),ID3 = c(2633,2635,2638,2642,2644),X1 = c("15:03", "15:01", "03:01","07","02"),X2 = c("03:01","03:05","07","15:01","34"),X3 = c("2","2","5","34","36"),X4 = c("6","6","5","4","6"),X5 = c("1","24","3","39","40"))

View(data_combined)
#I tried this but not get the desired result:
data_combined <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(df1,df2))

Comment: Hi alistaire. Can you help me now.

Comment: Your result data.frame has data that's not in `df1` or `df2`. You're getting to the point that it's probably easiest to directly overwrite subsets, although I don't really see any pattern by which you're doing so.